# Special triangles in convex polygons

Tags: mathematics, geometry, triangle

Given identical 30-60-90 triangles, what is the convex polygon with the highest number of sides that I can build from them?

This seems a very easy task by first look, but I’m totally stuck right now. The only thing I’m pretty sure of is that the polygon can at most have 12 sides, because a 150 degrees angle is the maximum convex angle I can find combining triangles. Obviously this does not guarantee that a dodecagon can be filled with 30-60-90 triangles.

Any suggestion? I was tempted to post it in Math, so if you think it is not pertinent I will shut the question down.

Comment: Did you mean "regular" polygon? It would be trivial to assemble an irregular polygon

Comment: The regular polygon with the highest number of sides that I can build is an hexagon indeed. I mean a general convex (I specified it in the title but didn’t add it in the text, just edited) polygon.

Comment: If say six — I can't think of anything better.

Comment: *"equal-sided 30-60-90 triangles"* is an impossibility unless you allow non-zero curvature. If you mean *"identical 30-60-90 triangles"* you should say that.

Comment: You’re right @Nij, I edited the question.

Comment: At the end of second paragraph, is "decagon" a typo for "dodegacon" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a convex dodecagon made of $50$  of those triangles.

> [image]

Can it be done with fewer?

Comment: I didn’t even thought that it could be done with such a small number of triangles! Great work!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to do better than a hexagon, if an irregular polygon is acceptable.

> One can construct an irregular [dodecagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagon) with $180$ identical 30-60-90 triangles as shown below. The dodecagon would have sides of alternating lengths, with ratio $4:\sqrt{12}$; as a specific size for the 30-60-90 triangle is not given.
> In the diagram below, the larger white triangles are not unit 30-60-90 triangles — they are actually made up of four, smaller 30-60-90 triangles, which is demonstrated in the top-left (shaded in pink). The image also includes two regular hexagons (of different sizes), a bunch of equilateral triangles, and some rectangles (all constructed from 30-60-90 triangles). It is not possible to get more than 12 sides because the minimum external angle that can be created from 30-60-90 triangles is 210 degrees. 
> [image: dodecagon constructed from 30-60-90 triangles]

It **is** also possible to construct an equilateral triangle or a hexagon. On reflection (and thanks to @Hugh's comment) you probably can't make a square — but can get relatively close to a square. By taking $\sqrt{3}$ by $1$ squares, each made from two triangles, you could stack them $n$ by $\frac{n}{\sqrt{3}}$ which, for sufficiently large $n$, would approach $1:1$.

Comment: Well done, @Penguino, I didn't think of making a dodecagon that big! You say that it's possible to make a square, but I don't think that's a perfect square...? Please correct  me if I'm wrong — regardless of you using two different sizes of triangle, all four sides contain a small "long leg" and a small "short leg". Other than that, the bottom and top edges contain: 2 big "hypotenusen" and 1 big "long leg". The left and right sides contain: 2 big "long legs" and 1 big "hypotenuse". Which, doesn't add up: $2n + 2n + n\sqrt{3} \neq 2n + n\sqrt{3} + n\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Yep - you are right - I sketched to soon :)

Comment: I've just suggested an edit, it corrects some grammar and adds math formatting. :)

Comment: Feel free to edit Hugh.

Comment: Great answer indeed! Did you find a ‘filling algorithm’ while building the figures, or just tried casual combinations? Btw, regarding the square, there are two triangles in the bottom left of the picture that are hypotenuse/long cathetus-sided, which is not allowed :)

Comment: @Francesco Arnaudo Pretty early on I realized that a regular dodecahedron wouldn't be tenable, so I assembled four triangles with alternating side length at 210 degree rotation to form four adjacent sides of a dodecahedron. Partially filled the inside region and realized then that 3x rotation  of that shape would form a hollow dodecahedron with an empty regular hexagon inside. So the problem was reduced to forming a 1+sqrt(3) sided regular hexagon with triangles. Halving the triangle size let me fill in the middle bit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that

> a convex dodecagon can indeed be made out of 30-60-90 tiles; you can see one rather complicated construction [here](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/eternity.html).

[EDITED to add:] The original version of this answer made a claim stronger than was correct; thanks to Jaap Scherphuis for pointing out my error.

Comment: That is not quite regular. If the hypotenuse of the triangle has length $1$, some sides have of the dodecahedron have length $7$, others have length $4\sqrt{3}\approx6.928$.

Comment: Whoops, of course you're right. But it's definitely _convex_.